# How can I perform a find in Mongo (meteor) that finds a document where an array matches?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to return a Cursor in Meteor (using MongoDB).

I'm looking to find documents (MessageThreads collection) where a field of participants exactly matches an array I pass in.

Below is a sample MessageThread document

```
{
  "_id": "YYSELCguhLurTeyNY",
  "creator": "RLmnidY6GypdqDXZu",
  "participants": [
    "SNhRq4vQpwFBjnTSH",
    "RLmnidY6GypdqDXZu"
  ],
}
```

When I perform an addMessage method, I'm trying to check first if a thread exists where `participants` exactly matches the array I pass in. This array will be formulated from the new message form `to`field.

So, the documents should only be returned if all my array of `participants` are inside the documents `participants` field but no other. Eg: If a third person existed in the document who wasn't part of the new message `to` field then that document should not be returned.

Currently this is my query, which is obviously too simplistic.

```
existingThread = MessageThreads.findOne(participants: participants)
```

Any pointers? Thank you

EDIT: I'm having an issue using the provided duplicate answer (but not yet allowed to comment on that other thread)

For some reason `existingThread` is still finding a document if the array is different but the `size` is true.

EDIT 2:

Below is the code for my entire method in the event that it can help decipher where I am going wrong. In coffeescript (please excuse the tabbing, can't get it working in SO, sorry).

```
Meteor.methods

newMessage: (recipientIds, messageContent) ->

if !Meteor.userId()
  return false

userId = Meteor.userId()

check recipientIds, [String]
check messageContent, String

participants = recipientIds
participants.push(userId)
participantCount = _.size(participants)

existingThread = MessageThreads.findOne participants:
  $size: participantCount
  $in: participants

if existingThread?
  console.log "Thread exists: #{existingThread._id}"

  MessageThreads.update existingThread,
    $addToSet: messages: {sender: userId, content: messageContent}
    $set: lastUpdated: new Date()


else
  newThreadId = MessageThreads.insert 
    creator: userId
    participants: participants
    messages: [
      {
        sender: userId
        content: messageContent
        createdAt: new Date()
      }
    ]
    lastUpdated: new Date()

  return newThreadId
```

Comment: Start with a google search for `mongodb array exact match`. That reveals a lot of useful-looking answers.

Comment: Many thanks, you are right I obviously wasn't searching very efficiently! This SO question appears to have one such answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774032/mongodb-find-exact-array-match-but-order-doesnt-matter

Comment: :P Good find, had forgotten that answer can apply to your case very well.

Comment: Didn't see it was also your answer thanks!

Comment: It turns out combining $all with $size seems to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need the **[`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)** operator in your query which selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements. As you want to return a cursor, **[`find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)** method is more appropriate since it returns a cursor. It does not immediately access the database or return documents. To access the documents in the cursor, cursors provide [**`fetch()`**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) to return all matching documents, [**`map()`**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/map) and [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/foreach) to iterate over all matching documents, [**`observe()`**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe) and [**`observeChanges()`**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes) to register callbacks when the set of matching documents changes.

For your case, an example implementation would look something like this:

```
var existingThreadsCursor = MessageThreads.find({ "participants": { "$all": participants} });
var count = 0;
existingThreadsCursor.forEach(function (thread){
    console.log("Thread with participants: " + JSON.stringify(thread.participants));
    count++;
});
```

Comment: Many thanks! I think I was misleading when I said I wanted to return a cursor, I think `findOne` is fine as I'm really trying to find out if such a thread exists or not. Would $all still work if I only want an exact match? I think it works if it finds all items in my array but would still work if other items were in it also?

Comment: Yes, it would still work as it matches documents where the field contains the array elements specified. So `findOne` in conjunction with `$all` would return a single document if it has an exact array match, else it returns null.

Comment: Thanks I think I am having an issue with $all where if the order of the array is different it doesn't match.

Comment: Well, in that case the answer I provided here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29774404/122005 will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, is it all possible that it's matching either the size or the names? Seemingly if it finds a thread with the same number of participants it puts the message in there?

Comment: @AndréGoldstein If using $size with $in then it's an implicit AND logic which looks for both the size of the array AND the elements in the specified array.

Comment: Thanks @chridam, the only problem seems to be that it's finding an existing record only if the count matches rather than both the count and the array match. I'll keep checking my code.