# Find exact match with nested arrays where order doesn't matter

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Assume this data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594d43d1da7887921c701575"),
    "hashSets" : [ 
        {
            "data1" : [ 
                "2bf2cededea424f47d64d33c511dd431", 
                "40499da7ee1456a2f79dc39a718aaf9b"
            ],
            "data2" : [ 
                "b068931cc450442b63f5b3d276ea4297",
                "16ebd6af0cadece819da7468a9fd79f4", 
                "8717cfca734e8987971f63b20eeb8024"
            ]
        },
        {
            "data1" : [ 
                "098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6", 
                "5A105E8B9D40E1329780D62EA2265D8A", 
                "AD0234829205B9033196BA818F7A872B"
            ],
            "data2" : [ 
                "8AD8757BAA8564DC136C1E07507F4A98"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I am trying to query for an exact match on "hashSets" however the order of objects in the "hashSets" array may differ AND the order of hashes in the data arrays may differ.

I found this post which is somewhat similar: [MongoDB Find Exact Array Match but order doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774032/mongodb-find-exact-array-match-but-order-doesnt-matter)

While using $size and $all makes sense, I'm not quite sure how to apply it with nested arrays / objects.

I was using this simple query, but it seems the order has to be the same:

```
db.analysis.find({hashSets:input.hashSets})
```

EDIT:
For clarity:

```
input.hashSets = [
    {
        "data1" : [ 
            "AD0234829205B9033196BA818F7A872B",
            "098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6", 
            "5A105E8B9D40E1329780D62EA2265D8A" 
        ],
        "data2" : [ 
            "8AD8757BAA8564DC136C1E07507F4A98"
        ]
    },
    {
        "data1" : [ 
            "40499da7ee1456a2f79dc39a718aaf9b",
            "2bf2cededea424f47d64d33c511dd431" 
        ],
        "data2" : [ 
            "b068931cc450442b63f5b3d276ea4297",
            "8717cfca734e8987971f63b20eeb8024",
            "16ebd6af0cadece819da7468a9fd79f4" 
        ]
    }
];
```

Note the contents of the data is the same, but the order of data in the various arrays has changed. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: what is `input.hashSets`? An example of the query you tried would be handy, it may be my bad but I can't really understand what you're looking for

Comment: input.hashSets is identical to the data above except the order of any of the arrays may differ.

Comment: Still not clear what you mean here. Is it "exactly" the same as the `"hasSets"` above, albeit possibly in reverse order? Or is the the value of the "keys" as in `"data1"` and `"data2"` that you are looking to match. Kind of would be much clearer if you simply showed the content of a sample `input.hashSets` variable

Comment: I ask because if it's just the same structure and I reverse the order of elements and pass it to `$all`, then the document will return just as expected. So I think you need to clarify your case with something that does not presently work for you.

Comment: Edited the post with more info. See above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be talking about the need for [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) with [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/).

For example, if I change around the structure of your sample to reverse the order of several elements:

```
[
        {
                "data2" : [
                        "8AD8757BAA8564DC136C1E07507F4A98"
                ],
                "data1" : [
                        "098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6",
                        "5A105E8B9D40E1329780D62EA2265D8A",
                        "AD0234829205B9033196BA818F7A872B"
                ]
        },
        {
                "data2" : [
                        "b068931cc450442b63f5b3d276ea4297",
                        "16ebd6af0cadece819da7468a9fd79f4",
                        "8717cfca734e8987971f63b20eeb8024"
                ],
                "data1" : [
                        "2bf2cededea424f47d64d33c511dd431",
                        "40499da7ee1456a2f79dc39a718aaf9b"
                ]
        }
]
```

Then I can apply that using [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) inside the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) condition to match the elements of the array, both in reverse order with "keys" in a different order:

```
db.hashsets.find({
  "hashSets": { 
    "$all": input.hashSets.map( e => ({ "$elemMatch": e  }) ) 
  }
})
```

Which would produce a "query" like:

```
{ 
  "hashSets": { "$all": 
      [
        {
                "$elemMatch" : {
                        "data2" : [
                                "8AD8757BAA8564DC136C1E07507F4A98"
                        ],
                        "data1" : [
                                "098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6",
                                "5A105E8B9D40E1329780D62EA2265D8A",
                                "AD0234829205B9033196BA818F7A872B"
                        ]
                }
        },
        {
                "$elemMatch" : {
                        "data2" : [
                                "b068931cc450442b63f5b3d276ea4297",
                                "16ebd6af0cadece819da7468a9fd79f4",
                                "8717cfca734e8987971f63b20eeb8024"
                        ],
                        "data1" : [
                                "2bf2cededea424f47d64d33c511dd431",
                                "40499da7ee1456a2f79dc39a718aaf9b"
                        ]
                }
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

If you need to take that further to the actual "keys", then change the mapping or the input to do it:

```
db.hashsets.find({ 
  "hashSets": { 
    "$all": input.hashSets.map( e => 
      ({ "$elemMatch": { "data2": { "$all": e.data2  }, "data1": { "$all": e.data1 } }}) )
  }
})
```

To produce a query like:

```
{ 
  "hashSets": { "$all": 
      [
        {
                "$elemMatch" : {
                        "data2" : { "$all": [
                                "8AD8757BAA8564DC136C1E07507F4A98"
                        ]},
                        "data1" : { "$all": [
                                "098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6",
                                "5A105E8B9D40E1329780D62EA2265D8A",
                                "AD0234829205B9033196BA818F7A872B"
                        ]}
                }
        },
        {
                "$elemMatch" : {
                        "data2" : { "$all": [
                                "b068931cc450442b63f5b3d276ea4297",
                                "16ebd6af0cadece819da7468a9fd79f4",
                                "8717cfca734e8987971f63b20eeb8024"
                        ]},
                        "data1" : { "$all": [
                                "2bf2cededea424f47d64d33c511dd431",
                                "40499da7ee1456a2f79dc39a718aaf9b"
                        ]}
                }
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

Or most flexibly and including size:

```
  db.hashsets.find({ 
    "hashSets": {
      "$all": input.hashSets.map( e => {
        var obj = {};
        Object.keys(e).forEach(k => {
          obj[k] = { "$all": e[k], "$size": e[k].length }
        });

        return { "$elemMatch": obj };
      }),
      "$size": input.hashSets.length
    }
  })
```

Which of course in "full" is like:

```
{
        "hashSets" : {
                "$all" : [
                        {
                                "$elemMatch" : {
                                        "data2" : {
                                                "$all" : [
                                                        "8AD8757BAA8564DC136C1E07507F4A98"
                                                ],
                                                "$size" : 1
                                        },
                                        "data1" : {
                                                "$all" : [
                                                        "098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6",
                                                        "5A105E8B9D40E1329780D62EA2265D8A",
                                                        "AD0234829205B9033196BA818F7A872B"
                                                ],
                                                "$size" : 3
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "$elemMatch" : {
                                        "data2" : {
                                                "$all" : [
                                                        "b068931cc450442b63f5b3d276ea4297",
                                                        "16ebd6af0cadece819da7468a9fd79f4",
                                                        "8717cfca734e8987971f63b20eeb8024"
                                                ],
                                                "$size" : 3
                                        },
                                        "data1" : {
                                                "$all" : [
                                                        "2bf2cededea424f47d64d33c511dd431",
                                                        "40499da7ee1456a2f79dc39a718aaf9b"
                                                ],
                                                "$size" : 2
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ],
                "$size" : 2
        }
}
```

Comment: Your answer including size is what I was looking for. Seems to work! Thanks for the help!