# How do I query nested objects within an array to match an $in array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Data structure

```
{
    users: [
        {id: "aaa"},
        {id: "bbb"},
        {id: "ccc"}
    ]
},
{
    users: [
        {id: "111"},
        {id: "222"},
        {id: "333"}
    ]
},


array: ["111", "222", "333"]
```

I want to get the document where every "id" matches my array, like $in does. But I don't want matches where only two of three matches. So in this case, the query should return the second document.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

#### Query an array for an element

```
const cursor = db.collection('inventory').find({
  users: [{id: "111"},{id: "222"},{id: "333"}]
});
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element

Related Q:
[MongoDB Find Exact Array Match but order doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774032/mongodb-find-exact-array-match-but-order-doesnt-matter)

Answer (score 0):

```
const userIds = ["abc", "123", ...]
```

I found this query to solve my problem.

```
    {
    $and: [
        {users: {$elemMatch: {id: {$in: userIds}}}}, 
        {users: {$size: userIds.length}}
    ]
}
```